# What is the Best Java LookAndFeel on Ubuntu?

Tags: 13.04, java, netbeans

Java applications does not look good on Linux platform, specially font rendering is awful !

I use `NetBeans IDE` for PHP Developing and GUI is not as good as it should be, for instance Eclipse has a very nice and native-looking GUI and font rendering is awesome.

I already have solved font rendering issue using `Infinality` Project and patched `OpenJDK7` using `infinality` font rendering.

What is the best Java LookAndFeel that makes java applications look as close to native apps as possible ? 
Im currently using `TinyLookAndFeel`.

Comment: This is a subjective question.  What looks good to you might differ from what looks good to me. You're not going to please everyone, so go with what looks good to you.

Comment: @EdManet You're right, actually my question is what `Java LookAndFeel` looks good to you ? maybe that is one nice looking `laf` that i am not aware of.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Nimbuzz` Look and feel.Its the best looking on linux.

Comment: Thanks, its `Nimbus` actually. I tried it, still not good